# How many different ways can these letters be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can the letters A, A, B, B, B, C, D, E be arranged if the letter C must be to the right of the letter D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider only the letters A, A, B, B, B, E (assuming you count similar letters as different).

there are $6!$ arrangements of those letters.

There are $6!$ arrangements of D, A, A, B, B, B, E. with letter D placed on the extreme-left position, as a result there $7 \times 6! = 7!$ arrangements of C placed on-the-right of D

There are $6 \times 5! = 6!$ arrangements of D, A, A, B, B, B, E. with letter D placed on the second-left position, as a result there $6 \times 6!$ arrangements of C placed on-the-right of D

There are $2! \times 4!$ arrangements of D, A, A, B, B, B, E. with letter D placed on the third-left position, as a result there $2! \times 4! \times 5$ arrangements of C placed on-the-right of D

.. etc..

UPDATE: 
doing an accurate (and complete counting) yields:

```
D pos.        Perms.                C right-of D
1             6!                    7*6! = 7! = 5040
2             6*5! = 6!             6*6! = 4320
3             2!*4!                 2!*4!*5 = 240
4             3!*3!                 3!*3!*4 = 144
5             4!*2!                 4!*2!*3 = 144
6             5!*6 = 6!             6!*2 = 1440
7             6!                    6! = 720

TOTAL:                              **12048** (total number of arrangements where C ir right of D)
```

All arrangements of A, A, B, B, B, E, C, D $= 8! = 40320$

$\frac{8!}{2} = 20160$ **which is not correct** (this result gives the number of arrangements where C is on the right, **but not on the right of D** necessarily)

Thus the answer is $12048$ (total number of arrangements where C is right of D)

If you count similar letters as exactly same a similar case-by-case analysis will give the result

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If you count the arrangements of those letters, exactly half will have $C$ to the right of $D$.

Answer (score 0):

There is $\frac{6\cdot 7}{2}$ ways to place C and D. (You may also check this by going through all the possibilities). For each choice there is then $5\choose 3$ ways to place the B:s. Finally there is 2! ways to place A and E.

Answer (score 0):

Number all the letters, $1$ - $8$, so they are distinct.  There are $8!$ ways of rearranging these letters.  Take away the numbering and we have duplicates.

There are $2!$ ways or arranging two As and $3!$ ways of arranging three Bs, so that means each pattern would appear in the above list $2!\times3!=12$ times.  So we need to divide $8!$ by $12$ to get the number of arrangements of letters.  $8!/12=3360$.

As [vadim123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73324/vadim123) indicated, half of these have the C to the left of the D and the other half have the C to the right of the D.  So you need to divide by 2.

Thus, the answer you want is $3360 / 2 = 1680$.

Answer (score 0):

> In how many different ways can the letters A, A, B, B, B, C, D, E be arranged if the letter C must be to the right of the letter D?

That depends on whether that is *somwhere* to the right, or *immediately* to the right.

The string "A,A,B,B,B,X,X,E" has $\frac{8!}{2!3!2!1!}$ permutations. Since in each rearrangement you can then replace the left most X with D and the right most with C you have counted the ways to arrange "A,A,B,B,B,C,D,E" such that C is always **somewhere** to the right of D. That is $1680$ ways.

The string "A,A,B,B,B,DC,E" (treating DC as one symbol) has $\frac{7!}{2!3!1!1!}$ permutations.  This counts the ways to arrange "A,A,B,B,B,C,D,E" such that C is **immediately** to the right of D. That is $420$ ways.

[Edit: this is also assuming that all the letters are used.]